# C++ Function that filters by name of plataform

Tags: c++

I have a function to show every game registered in my programme:

```
void games_per_plataform(void)
{
char type[TYPE];
PTRGM aux;
if (!head)
{
    printf("\n      No games!\n");
    getch();
    return;
}

//Show plataforms of registered games
printf("\n");
printf("      %-20s\n","plataforms of registered games");
for(aux=head;aux!=NULL;aux=aux->next)
{
    printf("\n      %-20s\n", aux->Plataform);
}
```

I need a function that shows only the games of some plataform that the user wants to see.  Here is what I already have:

```
//Show games filtered by plataform
printf("\n      Plataform - ");
scanf("%s",&tipo);
printf("\n      %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s\n","Name", "Plataform", "Genre", "Price");
for(aux=head;aux!=NULL;aux=aux->next)
{
    printf("      %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20f\n", aux->Name, aux->Plataform, aux->Genre, aux->Price);
}
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to filter the output in your loop:

```
scanf("%s",type);
...
int tln=strlen(type); 
for(aux=head;aux!=NULL;aux=aux->next)
{
    if (strncmp(aux->Plataform,type,tln)==0)
        printf("      %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20f\n", aux->Name, aux->Plataform, aux->Genre, aux->Price);
}
```

This solution also prints the entires when the platform start with what the user has enterred.  Note that I've kept your C style, and that there is a risk of buffer overflow in `scanf()`.